# How to implement NSTableView class using (MVC) archiciture?

Tags: cocoa

I want to implement MVC architicture in my project. So I have to implement NSObject class for NSTableView.But some delegate method is not called. How to implement this class? Please help me for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/TableView.html) can teach you what you need to know.

The [NSTableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) page lists some sample code for you to try out on your own